# Can I find the inverse function of the original function by using inverse function theorem?

Tags: functions, derivatives, inverse

I learn about the inverse function theorem which says the derivative of the inverse function is the reciprocal of the derivative of the original function, and I wonder if it is possible that I can find the inverse function of the original function by applying this theorem? e.g. If I have $$ f(x) = \frac{2^x}{2^x+1} $$
then I can find $$f^{-1}(x)$$ by $$f^{-1}(x)=\int\frac{dx}{f'(x)}.$$

Comment: Please, clarify what you are asking for. My answer might be wrong because you claim to use inverse function theorem which is used for the inverse of the derivative...

Comment: No, see my answer. Your argument would yield $(x^2)^{-1}=\int\frac{dx}{2x}=\frac12\log x$, which is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse function theorem says $$(f^{-1}(x))'=\frac1{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$
which can be reworked by integration,
$$f^{-1}(x)+C=\int\frac{dx}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}.$$
Unfortunately, $f^{-1}$ appears in both members and this is an integral equation, usually much more difficult than the function inversion itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's not likely to be helpful in a way that you're looking for.  Take a simpler example, $f(x)=\sin(x)$.  Then the inverse function theorem says that, there exists a $g_{x_0}(y)$ an inverse of $f(x)$ near $x_0$, and $g_{x_0}'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$.  If this were expressed in terms of $f(x)$, we could now integrate to find $g(y)$, but it's not.  The inverse function theorem tells you the inverse *as a function of $x$*, which is probably not enough for you.  In order to start integrating, we already have to answer the question: "okay, for a given $y$ value, what value of $x$ do I use to get the inverse from the inverse function theorem?"  In other words, you already need to know the inverse.